# My images ask for a password to the local network (Under ASP/IIS)

Tags: iis, authentication, asp-classic

Not quite sure how to troubleshoot this. I'm maintaining an ASP site, its mostly static, but there's this one include page which brings the menu.

Just recently I replaced some images, but now when I try the site, I get a prompt for a password as if It were looking for something on the local network!

I checked, all image paths are written up correctly, all images are unblocked (a W2k3 safety feature) and all images are set to allow-all on all users ... yet still, I get a password prompt!

Here's a sample page where it happens: http://www.iossolution.com/company/aboutus.asp (Windows only, it seems)

Thanks.

/mp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mauriciopastrana,

Check that the appropriate user has permission on the files in the windows file system. For W2K3 and IIS6 I think that user is typically NETWORK SERVICE.

Also check that the images directory has the intended authentication setup in IIS. You'll likely want to have the "enable anonymous access" checkbox checked and the "Integrated Windows Auth" box checked. You might also need to make sure that the IUSR_SERVERNAME user has access to the images.

Good luck!

Comment: Turns out that the only user allowed to view the files was the user that generated them (!). Thanks! (now going through all the images one a onebyone basis, phew!)

Comment: You should ACL with IIS_WPG, not Network Service - Allows you to change the AppPool ID without having to re-ACL everything.